# Change Pivot Font Size on Selection -Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: pivot, font-size, pivotitem

Whether we can change the Font size of header  in Pivot item dynamically?.I want to change the font size of Pivot item selected in windows Phone 8.1.
The item selected will be having greater font size . 
Please help.thanks in advance